# Why does my code return null?......i need snapshot to return a list of maps....but it says nosuchmethod error

Tags: flutter, dart

Why does my code return null?......i need snapshot to return a list of maps....but it says nosuchmethod error.Im trying to get the switch function to take urls from the list developed in the future in the future builder.is there a reason why the future does not return any value...in this case a list?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  return runApp(
    ScreenTimer(),
  );
}

class ScreenTimer extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<List> _getScreen1() async {
    List<Map<String, String>> runningShow;
    var response1 = await http.get(
        'https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/Shows/Morning_Show/Screen1.json');
    final String morningResponse = json.decode(response1.body);
    runningShow.add({'url1': morningResponse});
    var response2 = await http.get(
        'https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/Shows/Mid_morning/Screen1.json');
    final String midResponse = json.decode(response2.body);
    runningShow.add({'url2': midResponse});
    var response3 = await http.get(
        'https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/Shows/Kiss_Drive/Screen1.json');
    final String driveResponse = json.decode(response3.body);
    runningShow.add({'url3': driveResponse});
    var response4 = await http.get(
        'https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/Shows/Maloko_Show/Screen1.json');
    final String malokoResponse = json.decode(response4.body);
    runningShow.add({'url4': malokoResponse});
    return runningShow;
  }

  _switchFunction(List<Map<String, String>> runningShow) {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (Timer t) {
      String workingUrl;
      int timeHour = DateTime.now().hour;
      // int time_day = DateTime.now().weekday;
      switch (timeHour) {
        case (0):
        case (1):
        case (2):
        case (3):
        case (4):
        case (5):
        case (6):
        case (7):
        case (8):
        case (9):
          return workingUrl = runningShow[0]['url1'];
        case (10):
        case (11):
        case (12):
        case (13):
        case (14):
          return workingUrl = runningShow[1]['url2'];
        case (16):
        case (17):
        case (18):
          return workingUrl = runningShow[2]['url3'];
        case (19):
        case (20):
        case (21):
        case (22):
        case (23):
          return workingUrl = runningShow[3]['url4'];
        default:
          break;
      }
      print(workingUrl);
      return workingUrl;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Screen1')),
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getScreen1(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
            print(snapshot);
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.none:
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return Image.asset('assets/default.jpg');
              case ConnectionState.done:
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Error:${snapshot.error}');
                } else {
                  print('Fetched Urls are:${snapshot.data}');
                  var url = _switchFunction(snapshot.data);
                  return Image.network(
                    url,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    height: double.infinity,
                    width: double.infinity,
                  );
                }
                break;
              default:
                Card(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('No Images to Display'),
                  ),
                );
            }
            return Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add items to `runningShow` list which is null. You need to initialize the list like this:

```
List<Map<String, String>> runningShow = [];
```

**EDIT:**

Well, another problem is that `_switchFunction` doesn't return anything (you use `Timer.periodic` and I think you cannot return value from timer callback like this).

First of all, I changed `ScreenTimer` to `StatefulWidget`, so we can use `setState` to rebuild widget and also cancel timer in dispose method. Timer now only calls `setState`, widget is rebuilt and `_switchFunction` is called. You can also use if-else instead of switch -> shorter code.

Here is full example:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  return runApp(
    ScreenTimer(),
  );
}

class ScreenTimer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScreenTimerState createState() => _ScreenTimerState();
}

class _ScreenTimerState extends State<ScreenTimer> {
  Timer timer;
  Future<List<Map<String, String>>> runningShow;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    runningShow = _getScreen1();
    timer = Timer.periodic(
      Duration(seconds: 10),
      (_) => setState(() {}),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, String>>> _getScreen1() async {
    List<Map<String, String>> runningShow = [];
    var response1 = await http
        .get('https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/Shows/Morning_Show/Screen1.json');
    final String morningResponse = json.decode(response1.body);
    runningShow.add({'url1': morningResponse});
    var response2 = await http
        .get('https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/Shows/Mid_morning/Screen1.json');
    final String midResponse = json.decode(response2.body);
    runningShow.add({'url2': midResponse});
    var response3 = await http
        .get('https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/Shows/Kiss_Drive/Screen1.json');
    final String driveResponse = json.decode(response3.body);
    runningShow.add({'url3': driveResponse});
    var response4 = await http
        .get('https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/Shows/Maloko_Show/Screen1.json');
    final String malokoResponse = json.decode(response4.body);
    runningShow.add({'url4': malokoResponse});

    return runningShow;
  }

  String _switchFunction(List<Map<String, String>> runningShow) {
    int timeHour = DateTime.now().hour;
    if (timeHour >= 0 && timeHour < 10) {
      // 0 - 9
      return runningShow[0]['url1'];
    } else if (timeHour >= 10 && timeHour < 15) {
      // 10 - 14
      return runningShow[1]['url2'];
    } else if (timeHour >= 15 && timeHour < 19) {
      // 15 - 18
      return runningShow[2]['url3'];
    } else {
      // 19 - 23
      return runningShow[3]['url4'];
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Screen1')),
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: runningShow,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
            print(snapshot);
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.none:
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return Image.asset('assets/default.jpg');
              case ConnectionState.done:
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Error:${snapshot.error}');
                } else {
                  print('Fetched Urls are:${snapshot.data}');
                  var url = _switchFunction(snapshot.data);
                  return Image.network(
                    url,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    height: double.infinity,
                    width: double.infinity,
                  );
                }
                break;
              default:
                Card(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('No Images to Display'),
                  ),
                );
            }
            return Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: that helped a little but it still returns 'package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart':Failed assertion:line  23 pos 14: 'url !=null': is not true

Comment: this solves part of the issue..... it checks the time over and over again but doesnt check for changes in the server... i want this to be done everyday at midnight..... can i call main() again ? if not how can i achieve this?